# Using HTC Duo cameras to calculate distance

Tags: camera, htc-one-m8

Since my One M8s has two cameras, it should be possible to calculate how far away any object in view is. I can't see any way to do this within HTC's built-in apps, but I know they released an API for using the Duo camera capture and processing. So has someone already made an app that uses this? I don't want an app that calculates based on the person holding it and pointing towards the ground, because I want to measure to objects above me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried any of the measuring apps on play, They might have a dual camera support..

Most of them calculate your height and the distance it takes to reach the ground using the gyroscope

but i haven't heard of one for dual cameras.. It means you would have to manually configure the distance between cameras on every individual device .. It would be a nice app to see in development but it'd be a very small customer base to make an application around, considering the device compatibility wouldn't be very extensive !

Comment: Since HTC released an API, the distance between the cameras is a given. Besides, HTC have only made two phones with Duo cameras: the One M8 and the One M8s, which have the same body and thus the same distance between the cameras. Yes, on any other Duo camera phone (like whichever Oppo phone it is) the distance would have to be known, but I was hoping for a One M8-only app.

Comment: My only advice is to head over to the htc development site, Sign up and start the development yourself ! http://htcdev.com